# Sending Kaa events using raw TCP

Tags: tcp, kaa

I want to send events to Kaa platform using raw TCP and I don't want to use generated SDK for this, so I want to ask is there any way for doing this ?
And where can I find the documentation for using Kaa TCP protocol manually without SDK.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? What objection do you have to using the SDK?

Comment: @EJP I think generating SDK every time is acceptable when you working on strongly typed languages but in languages like python and for simply manage your nodes with create some event it is too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't do this.

There is a specification on [KaaTCP protocol](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/KaaTCP+channel) responsible for transport and [Binary platform protocol](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Binary+platform+protocol) (there is also Avro-based platform protocol) which responsible for serializing [Kaa services](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Transports#Transports-Kaaservicesanddatatransfer). You can try  to implement this protocols by yourself or reuse and adjust existed code on [GitHub](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa) for your needs but custom realization takes a lot of effort.

In release 1.0.0 planned to implement an ability to communicate with the server without generated SDK just via REST or popular IoT protocols such as CoAP or MQTT.